# How to handle delayed responses via HTTP, e.g., by polling?

Tags: http, response, delay, polling

When processing a request, it may happen that the server takes rather long time to come up with a response, such that there is the risk that the client runs into a timeout condition or the connection drops in between.

- How to let the client know that the response will take more time and
  specify when the client should ask again?
- Is there a suitable HTTP response status code to use, likely in conjunction with the
  “Retry-After” header field? (503 was suggested elsewhere, but this
  seems to be meant for situations where the server could not start
  processing the request.)
- And after the waiting time has elapsed, should the client re-send the original request, or is there a better way to poll?

I would suppose that the problem has already been addressed and solved in a standardized way, but for whatever reason am unable to find a good reference, e.g., an IETF document based on [RFC 7231](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231).